# Hortonworks HDP 3 : Error starting ResourceManager

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hortonworks-data-platform, hadoop3

I have installed a new cluster HDP 3 using ambari 2.7.

The problem is that resource  manager  service is not starting.

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/3.0/services/YARN/package/scripts/resourcemanager.py", line 275, in <module>
    Resourcemanager().execute()
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 353, in execute
    method(env)
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/3.0/services/YARN/package/scripts/resourcemanager.py", line 158, in start
    service('resourcemanager', action='start')
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/ambari_commons/os_family_impl.py", line 89, in thunk
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/3.0/services/YARN/package/scripts/service.py", line 92, in service
    Execute(daemon_cmd, user = usr, not_if = check_process)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/base.py", line 166, in __init__
    self.env.run()
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 160, in run
    self.run_action(resource, action)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 124, in run_action
    provider_action()
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/providers/system.py", line 263, in action_run
    returns=self.resource.returns)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 72, in inner
    result = function(command, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 102, in checked_call
    tries=tries, try_sleep=try_sleep, timeout_kill_strategy=timeout_kill_strategy, returns=returns)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 150, in _call_wrapper
    result = _call(command, **kwargs_copy)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 314, in _call
    raise ExecutionFailed(err_msg, code, out, err)
resource_management.core.exceptions.ExecutionFailed: Execution of 'ulimit -c unlimited; export HADOOP_LIBEXEC_DIR=/usr/hdp/3.0.0.0-1634/hadoop/libexec && /usr/hdp/3.0.0.0-1634/hadoop-yarn/bin/yarn --config /usr/hdp/3.0.0.0-1634/hadoop/conf --daemon start resourcemanager' returned 1.
```

Comment: This error message is not helpful since it's Ambari's error message.  If you want to find out why RM failed, you might want to post the ResourceManager log.

Comment: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/YARN-Registry-DNS-Start-failed-Hortonworks-3/td-p/218794